# Fitting dropbars on Whyte 429 - advised road levers wont match Deore rear-mech, Alternative wanted matching rear mech/gravel shifters

Tags: shimano, upgrades, conversion, dropouts

I have a Whyte 429, aiming to switch to drop bars but not sure I can match the rear mech with Road/lever shifters.

Seeking an alternative, i.e., installing a matching rear mech and road/gravel shifters.

But need comfort of know the dropouts will hold the new rear mech e.g., a GRX set up

Grateful for any advice you can give

Many thanks, Iain

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Is this just a restatement of the question you asked earlier?

Comment: Hi 1st question was for a solution match levers to the existing rear derailleur. This one is to ask for a recommendations to replace the derailleur with a matching set of levers, and also to confirm if the hangers would match the replacement rear mech. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Using road levers with mtb derailleurs is called a "mullet" setup. As I understand it, this is easier with SRAM than Shimano, but there are some viable Shimano configurations. [See here](https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/).

Derailleur bolts and hanger coordinates are almost completely standardized (although replaceable hangers are not standardized at all). So you shouldn't have trouble changing the rear derailleur. Looking at a picture of this bike, I see nothing out of the ordinary around the dropout.

If you wind up replacing your rear derailleur with a GRX (for example), make sure the new mech will accommodate your maximum sprocket size.

Comment: Adam, you’re a star. Really appreciate your feedback, I’ll give this a good read.